# Should I focus more on the concepts or on the calculations?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, learning

I passed the real analysis course at my college and now, after 3 years, im not that good anymore at integrating, solving big complicated limits etc. But I still remember the concepts behind them. Now, since I'm trying to self-study some topics that I'm not familiar with (topology, galois theory etc), as an aspiring engineer, I was wondering if I shouldn't move to the next topic until I'm very good at doing every exercise (“calculate the integral of” “calculate the limit of” etc) with the risk of one day forgetting almost everything or if i should focus more on understanding the concepts and use a computer for the calculations.

Comment: Seeing as you're aspiring to be an engineer, I guess it would be fine for you to use computers. It never hurts to make, and be good at the exercises though, since they get you an understanding of the concepts. It might not seem like it at first, but being really good at making the exercises is really just an extension of understanding the concepts.

Comment: You don't have to be good at computations to learn abstract Mathematics.  If you love rigor and logic you should go ahead. But you should do exercises that the conceptual in nature.

Comment: Yeah well, maybe it's not really clear in the question, but I don't mean doing all the exercises at the computer, I mean, for example in calculus, focusing on solving basics/intermediate limits instead of particular cases or very complicated ones

Comment: Calculus $\neq$ Real-Analysis. Know the theory if you want to learn abstract math, not the calculations. On the flip-side, if you ever need calculations as an engineer, use a computer.

Comment: I said for example.. I know it's not the same thing since I even attended the class

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are studying the math to eventually use it instead of teaching it, you should be fine moving forward.  If you can solve a "word problem" by creating the appropriate integral, having W|A solve it, and then interpreting the result appropriately, that is an "effective use of technology" that will model your professional work anyways.

Anyways, the topics you're heading towards are much more fun than boring old Analysis anyways....